# Django foreign key(ManyToMany) field isn't added to DB table

Tags: python, django, database

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    mLeader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    mName = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='-')
    mTel = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='-')
    mAddress = models.TextField(default='-')
    mType = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A') # A : Daycare Center, B : private educational institute, C : Church, D : ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='Organization')

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.mName

class OrganizationLeader(models.Model):
    #private info
    mUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='Leader')
    # mName = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='-')

class BusLine(models.Model):
    mOrganization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    mName = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='-')
    mIsPrivate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    mCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mIsCycle = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='lines')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('mCreated', )

class BusStation(models.Model):
    mName = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='-')
    mCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mOrder = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    mIsStart = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mIsEnd = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mBusLine = models.ManyToManyField('BusLine', blank=True, null=True)

    #변수명이 고정돼있어 접미사 붙이지 않음
    mpoint = models.PointField(default=None)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='stations')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['mOrder']

class Bus(models.Model):
    mDriver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    mDriving = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mCurrentStation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mBusLine = models.ForeignKey('BusLine', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    mArrive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #LSB Data
    #변수명이 고정돼있어 접미사 붙이지 않음
    mpoint = models.PointField(default=None)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='buses')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Latitude  = self.mpoint.y
        self.Longitude = self.mpoint.x
        super(Bus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('mCreated', )

class PassengerLogManager(models.Manager):
    def create_log(self, id):
        log = self.create(mBusId = id)
        return log

class PassengerLog(models.Model):
    mBusId = models.IntegerField()
    mCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    #JSON 필드에 버스의 한 회차 정류장당 탑승자 리스트가 저장됨
    mLog = JSONField()
    objects = PassengerLogManager()

class AppUser(models.Model):
    #private info
    mUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    mBaseDestination = models.ForeignKey(
        BusStation,
        verbose_name = 'BaseDestination',
        default = '-',
    )
    mName = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'UserName',
        max_length=30,
        blank = False,
        default = '-'
    )

    mChild = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through = 'ParentToChildEntry',
        verbose_name = 'Child',
        through_fields = ('mParent','mChild'),
        symmetrical = False,
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='User')
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.mName

class ParentToChildEntry(models.Model) :
    mName = models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        verbose_name = 'Title',
        blank = False,
        default = '-'
    )
    mParent = models.ForeignKey(
        AppUser,
        verbose_name = 'Parent',
        related_name = 'Parent',
    )

    mChild = models.ManyToManyField(
        AppUser,
        verbose_name = 'Child',
        related_name = 'Child',
    )
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.mName

class OrganizationToUserEntry(models.Model) :
    mName = models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        verbose_name = 'Title',
        blank = False,
        default ='-'
    )
    mOrganizations = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        verbose_name = 'Organization'
    )
    mUsers = models.ManyToManyField(
        AppUser,
        verbose_name = 'Users'
    )
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.mName
```

The code above is a Bus managing system model.(Django version 1.11.4)
Firstly when I tried to start and test this in admin,

> the error (1054, "Unknown column 'DataMng_appuser.mBaseDestination_id' in 'field list'")

aroused so I flushed DB and migrated model.
However, When I tried to migrate this model, system returned me

> [WARNINGS: DataMng.BusStation.mBusLine: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.]

I repeatedly found how to solve this problem but I couldn't find.
Please tell me what I should do T_T. Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is not a problem, its a warning. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid
Thank you for replying me. But If I ignore this, I think I can't solve the 1054 error.

Comment: did you try to run after migrate?